# seaborn: how can I tell it a categorical variable has a specific color?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm playing with the Gapminder dataset, it has some information about the world in the last 200 years or so. One of the variables is `continent`, which can be four categorical values: `africa`, `americas`, `asia` and `europe`

I'm doing some animation to see how the different values change over the years, I'm doing a scatter plot and using the `continent` column as source of hue, like:

```
axes = sns.scatterplot(x='income',
                      y='life_exp',
                      data=df[df.year == year],
                      hue='continent',
                      size='population',
                      palette="Set2",
                      sizes=(20, 200))
```

This works, but the names of the continents are not always in the same order. Of course I could use `data=df[df.year == year].sort_values('continent')`, and the problem is solved. But I believe this makes my program slower making it skip some frames.

So, is there a way to tell seaborn that `americas` will always be the first color of its palette, `africa` second and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `hue_order` parameter.

```
axes = sns.scatterplot(x='income',
                      y='life_exp',
                      data=df[df.year == year],
                      hue='continent',
                      hue_order=['americas', 'africa', 'asia', 'europe'],   % set order for hues
                      size='population',
                      palette="Set2",
                      sizes=(20, 200))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `palette=color_dict`, which is a dictionary format that associates a country with a color.

```
color_dict = dict({'Africa':'brown',
                  'Asia':'green',
                  'Europe': 'orange',
                  'Oceania': 'red',
                   'Americas': 'dodgerblue'})

axes = sns.scatterplot(x='income',
                      y='life_exp',
                      data=df[df.year == year],
                      hue='continent',
                      size='population',
                      palette=color_dict,
                      sizes=(20, 200))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it also worked but I preferred the other answer because I'm so lame on doing color palettes, I prefer sns to bring its own

Comment: You could learn more than one approach, but isn't my answer worth it?